# DNS over VPN service

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, openvpn, dnsmasq

I have [`OpenVPN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN) server with few devices connected in (web server, Raspberry Pi, netbook and phones).

I want to create DNS over VPN (custom `.vpn` domain).

I have done it with [`dnsmasq`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) and `address` directive in config file

Example:

```
address=/home.vpn/10.8.0.1
address=/raspberrypi.vpn/10.8.0.16
...
```

I changed few settings in `OpenVPN` server to set custom DNS server for clients and everything is working but I am afraid that `dnsmasq` is not the best way to do this.

Comment: dnsmasq is a fine way to do this.

Comment: @dirkt I afraid about that because I do not really understand what mean that `dnsmasq` is a _"DNS forwarder"_.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not really understand what mean that dnsmasq is a "DNS forwarder".

Look at the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dnsmasq):

> dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
>
> [...]
>
> Dnsmasq accepts DNS queries and either answers them from a small, local, cache or forwards them to a real, recursive, DNS server. It loads the contents of /etc/hosts so that local hostnames which do not appear in the global DNS can be resolved and also answers DNS queries for DHCP configured hosts.

So if you ask `dnsmasq` about names in your custom `*.vpn` domain, it will answer directly. If you ask `dnsmasq` about other names, like `superuser.com`, it will **forward** the query to your ISP's DNS server, cache the answer, and send the answer back.

Which is exactly what you want for your purpose.